# How to connect optical fiber between a color sensor on PCB, and a display screen that is being tested?

Tags: sensor, connector, fiber, fiber-optics

Does anyone have an idea how you would connect a fiber cable to a [TCS3430 color sensor](https://ams.com/en/tcs3430) IC that is soldered on a board? I've searched for connectors on the internet but none of them are for mounting on a PCB. The fiber cable has to be placed vertically on the color sensor so that the sensor can sense the color and I will read it out with an Arduino. The design of the board can be adjusted if there is a solution.

The light source is a display and at the moment the sensors are placed directly on the display for measuring the RGB value to see if the display is still producing the correct color in extreme temperatures. Hence why I want to place the PCB outside the extreme temperatures. The idea was to connect fiber to the display inside, with the sensors outside and measure it that way.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Optical fiber cable on screen"?

Comment: Is it acceptable to directly place (even touch) the fiber to the sensor window?  Do you need to be able to unscrew the fiber rather than glue?  If so, I would screw a bulkhead connector directly above the chip to the PCB with a spacer and connectorize the fiber.  If you need optics, then this gets more complex and I would design the PCB to slot into an optical assembly.

Comment: I would add a little 3D-printed "thingy" that is screwed to the PCB above the IC and guides the fibre. With some sort of clamping mechanism (on the diameter) of the fibre. By doing so, you shield the sensor against environment light and make the fibre "fixed but swapable".

Comment: I mean the light source is a display and at the moment the sensors are placed directly on the display for measuring the rgb value to see if the display is still producing the correct color around dE =5 as the example color in extreme temperatures. thats why i want to place the PCB outside the extreme temperatures. So the idea was to connect the display inside with the sensors outside with fiber cables and measure it that way but i'm new to fiber so i'm still figuring out what fiber i should use and how it would connect to the pcb

Comment: I would expect the fiber to affect the readings

Comment: for sure but if you take a reference value with the fibers en you compare your by example production run the affect will cancel out

Answer (score 0):

As fibre optic connectors are mechanically the same as their "parent" eletrical connectors, consider an electrical connector mounted over the sensor chip.  Drill out the insulated centre part and you should have something which will mount over the chip, which is 2.4 x 1.75 mm and 1mm tall off the PCB.

For example this SMA connector, whose metal parts will mate with an SMA fibre connector.

[image]
*From [GTK](https://www.gtk.co.uk/products/connectors/microwave-and-rf/sma)* approx 4 mm between legs.

You'll have to pay attention to vertical spacing so that the end of the SMA fibre is the appropriate distance, perhaps by raising the connector on an extra layer of PCB.

Comment: okay thankyou for the advise i will try this! i think drilling out will be the hardest part. but i'm still open to other suggestions.

Comment: Drilling it out might be easier than it looks because it's just the insulation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a connector like this:

[SMD_22 Visual Communications Company | DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/visual-communications-company-vcc/SMD-22/4515621)

It's up to you whether this has compatible dimensions to the device in question, or finding a more exact fit; this should at least get you started on where to look.